# Unable to call function within jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a function in this javascript code. My code needs to check for whether the user selects `var num`, `var letters` and `var symbols` to be `true` or `false`. In the code, I preset the values but I still search the object `choices` for the variables that are `true` and `push` it into the array `choices_made`. However, since I need to randomly choose the order in which the `num, letters and symbols` appear, I randomly choose the class based on the `Math.random()`. However, it doesn't show me the `alert(jumbled_result)` afterwards.

http://jsfiddle.net/bdaxtv2g/1/

HTML

```
<input id="num" type="text" placeholder="Enter desired length">
<br/><br/>
<input id="press" type="button" value="jumble it up">
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var fns={};

$('#press').click(function(){
    var length = parseInt($('#num').val());
    var num = true;
    var letters = true;
    var symbols = false;

    gen(length, num, letters, symbols);
});

function gen(len, num, letters, sym){
    var choices = {
            1:num,
            2:letters,
            3:sym
        };
    var choice_made = ['0'];
    var choice = 0;
    var jumbled_result = '';

    for(x in choices){
        if(choices[x]==true){
            choice_made.push(x);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        var funName = 'choice';
        choice = Math.round(Math.random() * (choice_made.length-1));

        funName += choice_made[choice];
        jumbled_result = fns[funName](jumbled_result);
    }

    alert(jumbled_result);
}

fns.choice0 = function choice0(jumbled_result){
    var numbers = '0123456789';
    return jumbled_result += numbers.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * numbers.length));
}

fns.choice1 = function choice1(jumbled_result) {
    var alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    return jumbled_result += alpha.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * alpha.length));
}

});
```

Comment: fns.choice2 function definition is missing and can you explain more about your code? Like what you are trying to achieve by numbers, letters and symbols?

Comment: I am trying to jumble up the numbers, letters and symbols depending on whether chooses to have numbers, letters or symbols in the jumbled_result text. I left out fns.choice2 because the `var symbols=false` so it wouldn't be in the `choice_made` array. The current code should only call fns.choice0 or fns.choice1 but it isn't calling either. Not sure why though.

Comment: If I remove the `funName` and instead use jumbled_result = fns['choice0'](jumbled_result); or jumbled_result = fns['choice1'](jumbled_result); everything works fine but I can't choose between the `numbers` or `letters`. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bdaxtv2g/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never declare functions within document.ready of jQuery. The functions should be declared during the first run(unless in special cases).

Here is a working code made out of your code. What I have done is just removed your functions out of document.ready event.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#press').click(function() {
    var length = parseInt($('#num').val());
    var num = true;
    var letters = true;
    var symbols = false;

    gen(length, num, letters, symbols);
  });
});

var fns = {};

function gen(len, num, letters, sym) {
  var choices = {
    1: num,
    2: letters,
    3: sym
  };
  var choice_made = ['0'];
  var choice = 0;
  var jumbled_result = '';

  for (x in choices) {
    if (choices[x] == true) {
      choice_made.push(x);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var funName = 'choice';
    choice = Math.round(Math.random() * (choice_made.length - 1));

    funName += choice_made[choice];
    jumbled_result = fns[funName](jumbled_result);
  }

  alert(jumbled_result);
}
fns.choice0 = function choice0(jumbled_result) {
  var numbers = '0123456789';
  return jumbled_result += numbers.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * numbers.length));
}

fns.choice1 = function choice1(jumbled_result) {
  var alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  return jumbled_result += alpha.charAt(Math.round(Math.random() * alpha.length));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="num" type="text" placeholder="Enter desired length">
<br/>
<br/>
<input id="press" type="button" value="jumble it up">
```

Comment: Not sure if I am missing anything, but it isn't working even the code snippet above.

Comment: Its working for me. I hope u are entering values between 1 and 3? A fiddle will help perhaps? https://jsfiddle.net/wffso7ke/

Comment: It is working but only if I press the button multiple times. Not sure why it is doing that. It should be able to work for any number of characters since there is a `for` loop.

Comment: That, my friend, is a logical issue. The code *choice = Math.round(Math.random() * (choice_made.length-1));* has Math.random() sometimes resulting in the value of "choice" as 2 or something else. In those cases, your logic fails.

Comment: It all works if I make `var choice_made = []` instead of `var choice_made = ['0']` and change `choice0` into `choice1` and `choice1` into `choice2`

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the way the object choices have been intitialized.. Try this..

```
       var choices = {
            0:num,
            1:letters,
            2:sym
        };
```

And also

```
 var choice_made = [];
```

JS fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/8dw7nvr7/2/